# How to prevent downloading PDF file when displaying on web pages?

Tags: java, javascript, html

How to prevent downloading **PDF** file when displaying on web pages?

I tried the *content disposition inline*  but it didn't work.

How can i do this ?

Comment: use `<iframe src='path of file'></iframe>` to show a pdf file on browser.

Comment: I done with that but problem is It was downloading with idm I need to prevent that one help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to render the PDF to JPEG or some other image format and only serve the rendered images to the user. Some of the PDF libraries allow you to render PDF's to other file formats.

Another option may be to send/redirect the PDF through to an online PDF viewing app in the same way Google does with attachments in GMail. That way the user sees a JPEG of the PDF and cannot download the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of searching, trying tons of plugins, viewers, embedders, etc., I finally came up with a solution.  It's a combination of a paid plugin and a free plugin.  The free plugin I'm using is "Prevent Files / Folders Access" https://wordpress.org/plugins/prevent-file-access/ which protects the url of the PDF if somebody manages to get it by viewing page source.  And I purchased PDF Poster: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pdf-poster/  However, I'm waiting for this plugin developer to answer my request for a bit of CSS to add to it to enable vertical scrolling and the hand tool both by default. I would have preferred a free solution, but this is the best I could come up with, and I needed to move ahead and get my hundreds of embeds done.  I hope this is helpful to someone else out there.